# Trouble returning the affected rows on batch insert using SQLSRV

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, sqlsrv

I am using codeignitor 2.1.4 and I inserting a bunch of rows using insert_batch.  I am connected to SQL Server 2008 database using the SQLSRV driver.  The query runs fine but when I run the affected_rows() function I am getting a weird result.  Please note that I have made the change in the affected_rows function for the bug so that isn't the problem.

What I am seeing is the returned number being chopped off after 2 digits.  So if the inserted rows were say 343 I would get 43.  If the affected rows were 35312, I would get 12 returned.

I am wondering if anyone else has seen this type of behaviour?  I have checked the return variable type and it is INT so its not that.  I am lost as to where the error or change is taking place.  Its almost like the return value is being taken as modulus 100 and returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking around I found the oversight in the insert_batch and update_batch functions in Codeigniter.

Because the inserts and updates are changed in 100 rows at a time the affected_rows function only sees the last ($rows%100) rows as that would be the last insert/update done.

The solution I found was provided in this link:

[Affected rows solution](http://webaurum.blogspot.ca/2012/10/codeigniter-affected-rows-fix-on-db.html)

It doesn't say it in the post there but you need to alter the insert_batch and update_batch functions in the system/database/DB_active_rec.php file.